# SSL Certificate Invalid on localhost

Tags: ssl, https, localhost, certificate, mamp-pro

I'm trying to secure my localhost website (which is on MAMP pro) on Chrome (V68), so far I've done the following things:

- Generated the certificate and certificate key files through MAMP
- Added the certificate to the keychain access and set to always trust
- Dragged the certificate from Chrome, double clicked and made sure it was set to always trust

Looking at the Chrome developer security tools it says the following:
[image]

Comment: If you are planning on buying an SSL cert at some point to put your site in production, then why not just use that cert?  It should automatically work with Chrome and any other modern browser.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The production site uses Let's Encrypt so how would I modify that certificate to be valid for the dev site?

Comment: You can't, unless it is on the same domain or maybe subdomain.  For local testing, you may just turn off SSL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I need the SSL on dev to do serviceworkers which require valid SSL certificates unfortunately

Comment: All I can say is that the certificate was created incorrectly. It should have a valid subject alternative name and common name that contains the hostname that the same as you use to connect to the site in chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Mamp hasn't been great about fixing this bug, they need to generate more information in the SSL Cert.  To fix it, you'll need to create a conf file and run some terminal commands.  this has been working for me

**FIRST: The conf file sample.local.conf** 
replace sammple.local with your local site url

```
[ req ]
default_bits       = 4096
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions     = req_ext

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName                 = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default         = US
stateOrProvinceName         = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = NEW YORK
localityName                = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default        = NEW YORK
organizationName            = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default    = SAMPLE
commonName                  = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_max              = 64
commonName_default          = sample.local

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1   = sample.local
```

first make the .KEY

```
openssl genrsa -out sample.local.key 4096
```

make the .CSR

```
openssl req -new -sha256 \
   -out sample.local.csr \
   -key sample.local.key \
   -config sample.local.conf
```

then

```
openssl req -text -noout -in sample.local.csr
```

create the .CRT

```
openssl x509 -req \
    -days 3650 \
    -in sample.local.csr \
    -signkey sample.local.key \
    -out sample.local.crt \
    -extensions req_ext \
    -extfile sample.local.conf
```

Then, on a mac, instead of going through the keychain, you can run the following command in terminal

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain sample.local.crt
```

Comment: sofar the bug has been fixed in the newer versions of MAMP 5.  you still need to trust the cert at the end

Comment: Chrome still marks this site as "not secure" even though the certificate is "valid"! Probably because it is 'self-signed'

Comment: If it is still marking at insecure you did not complete the steps correctly,  this method is still working for me

Comment: Its working now, the system probably needed a restart